# PLManagedAlbumList identifier warning on console

Tags: xcode8, ios10

Is there a cure for this:

warning: dynamic accessors failed to find @property implementation for 'identifier' for entity AlbumList while resolving selector 'identifier' on class 'PLManagedAlbumList'.  Did you remember to declare it @dynamic or @synthesized in the @implementation ?

Comment: did you manage solve this?

Comment: I don't remember. If it were a showstopper I guess I would've remembered to supply an answer. But I guess the warning is still there, with the employer whose code got it.

Answer (score 4):

This answer won't help you since your warnings are coming from an Apple framework rather than your own code. But I'll go ahead and put it here in case other people are searching on the same warning.

In my case I was getting a similar warning from my own code, which was puzzling since I was definitely declaring my @property as @dynamic. The problem was that while my main class was added to my target, the auto-generated Core Data category (e.g. `MyClass+CoreDataProperties.m`) wasn't. Adding it to the target silences the warnings.

The code works fine either way, I think this is just a stricter warning new to Xcode 8. Unfortunately it will be up to Apple to fix the log spew coming from their own frameworks.